# Allow specific number of users to access a method in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock

I want to do the following idea in java if that is possible:

I have a synchronized method that has over 1000 line of code, and it takes a long time to finish.
Many users request the same method at the same time so the performance is awfully bad.

What I am thinking is that I want to open this method for a certain number of user concurrently (lets say 5) rather than 1 user at a time in the synchronized.
Is this doable in java?
And what technology I have to know in order to do it?

Comment: Check this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386544/limit-maximum-threads-executing-at-time-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use semaphore as shown below:-

```
// Grant access to only 5 permits
Semaphore sp = new Semaphore(5);




    public void myMethod() {
        sp.acquire();
        //...
        sp.release();
    }
```

Sempahore gives you the functionality of controlling how many threads can execute your method by specifying the number of permits in its constructor. Since you want not more than 5 threads to execute concurrently you can specify 5 in the constructor of Semaphore. Now when different threads call your myMethod , you restrict the access by using either sp.tryAcquire() if you dont want the thread to wait till it gets permit or you can call sp.acquire() to make the threads wait if already 5 other threads have got the permit . Calling release() does the release of the permit for a new thread to be able to access your method

Comment: I have used the Semaphore in J2SE application and the result is exactly as I want, can I use the same method in J2EE application? what I was thinking is that I want to use the http request as the thread, is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can use the method containing Semaphore in J2EE application. Each HTTP request anyways is processed as a seperate thread by the container.